IOS Custom push notifications using flutter frame work
I need custom categories push notifications implement using flutter_local_notification package.
I want notification categories like in the ,
I am writing below code
final List<DarwinNotificationCategory> darwinNotificationCategories1 =
    <DarwinNotificationCategory>[
      DarwinNotificationCategory(
        darwinNotificationCategoryText,
        actions: <DarwinNotificationAction>[
          DarwinNotificationAction.text(
            'text_1',
            'Action 1',
            buttonTitle: 'Send',
            placeholder: 'Placeholder',
          ),
        ],
      ),
      DarwinNotificationCategory(
        darwinNotificationCategoryPlain,
        actions: <DarwinNotificationAction>[
          DarwinNotificationAction.plain('id_1', 'Action 1'),
          DarwinNotificationAction.plain(
            'id_2',
            'Action 2 (destructive)',
            options: <DarwinNotificationActionOption>{
              DarwinNotificationActionOption.destructive,
            },
          ),
          DarwinNotificationAction.plain(
            navigationActionId,
            'Action 3 (foreground)',
            options: <DarwinNotificationActionOption>{
              DarwinNotificationActionOption.foreground,
            },
          ),
          DarwinNotificationAction.plain(
            'id_4',
            'Action 4 (auth required)',
            options: <DarwinNotificationActionOption>{
              DarwinNotificationActionOption.authenticationRequired,
            },
          ),
        ],
        options: <DarwinNotificationCategoryOption>{
          DarwinNotificationCategoryOption.hiddenPreviewShowTitle,
        },
      )
    ];
    final DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsDarwin =
    DarwinInitializationSettings(
      requestAlertPermission: true,
      requestBadgePermission: false,
      requestSoundPermission: false,
      onDidReceiveLocalNotification:
          (int id, String? title, String? body, String? payload) async {
        //   didReceiveLocalNotificationSubject.add(
        //     ReceivedNotification(
        //       id: id,
        //       title: title,
        //       body: body,
        //       payload: payload,
        //     ),
        //   );
      },
      notificationCategories: darwinNotificationCategories1,
    );



    var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
        android: initializationSettingsAndroid, iOS: initializationSettingsDarwin);


In my app show notification like below 
I need like first image implement same in my app.

You cannot customise the notification settings shown in the settings app - This is defined by iOS.  You can provide a settings screen in your app to customise your notifications.  You can also create a settings bundle to add your own settings in your app's settings in the settings app.  These will be written to UserDefaults

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
